# Microsoft Graph API Planner Task Detail with hyperlinks

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

wanted to add hyperlinks to Microsoft's Planner Task Details,. but don't see a way to use html.  When I add a task detail with html, it displays as plain text with no formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The description currently does not support formatting options, including links. For specifically adding links that show up with the task, you can use "ExternalReferences" on the task details. [Update TaskDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannertaskdetails-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) page has an example on how to add a link, and more information is available on the [externalReferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannerexternalreferences?view=graph-rest-beta) documentation.